# Why am i unable to color a listview fields background in android studio?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I am attempting to color the background of listview fields based on some information within the string shown in the list view. I have tried a few things such as iterate through the children of the listview(which returns null and I am unsure why) and using the line or some variation of - listView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

As far as i can tell this is a simple thing to do and i cannot figure out how to perform this action. I would even take colouring the text of the fields instead of the background. Any attempt to access the children of my listview returns a null exception even though i can see them there. When i run listView.getChildCount() i receive 0 even when the results are 3 or more listviews which i can see are there. How do i color the background of these listviews based on text within the listview field?

```
public class DatepickerListFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;
String selectedDate;
String[ ] items;
Double[ ] mags;
LinkedList<ItemClass> test;
int i,j;




@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState
)
{

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_datepickerlistfragment, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.mylist);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        selectedDate = bundle.getString("selected_date");
        Log.d("UI thread", "Date received: " + selectedDate);
        finditems();
        Log.d("UI thread", "array of items length: " + items.length);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.activity_listview, items);
        Log.d("UI thread", "CHILD COUNT IS: " + listView.getChildCount());


        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //View itemView = listView.getChildCount();
        Log.d("UI thread", "CHILD COUNT IS: " + listView.getCount());

        if(items.length == 0){
            noDatesmatch();
        }
        


    }


    return v;
}

public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{


    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);



}

public void finditems(){

    DateActivity dateActivity = (DateActivity) getActivity();
    test = dateActivity.templist;
    i = 0;
    Log.d("UI thread", "test list size is: " + test.size());
    for(ItemClass item : test){
        if(item.getdate().contains(selectedDate)){
            i++;
            Log.d("UI thread", "item with date in it found");
        }
    }
    String[ ] temp = new String[i]; Log.d("UI thread", "temp array length is" + temp.length);
    mags = new Double[i];

    j = 0;
    for(ItemClass item : test){
        if(item.getdate().contains(selectedDate)){
            temp[j] = item.getTitle();
            mags[j] = item.getstrength();
            j++;

        }
    }

    items = temp;
}

public void noDatesmatch(){
    String[ ] errors = new String[]{"Nothing found for specified date please try another date"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.activity_listview, errors);
    Log.d("UI thread", "NOTHING FOUND SHOULD BE SHOWING ERROR MESSAGE");
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);//possibly create new activity_listview for custom error message

}

public void colorFields(){

}
```

} // End of listview Fragment

Comment: You should do this within the adapter.  You can subclass `ArrayAdapter` to do that.

Comment: @RyanM thanks for this ill take a look. I am still very early in my learning experience, would you advise using another way of displaying information that makes it easy to access and color the fields? the method you have recommended might be a bit above my skill level currently.

Comment: I would personally recommend using RecyclerView instead of ListView (disclosure: I'm the maintainer), but that's a little more complicated (there's [a tutorial](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview)).  Either way, you really need to make any changes that depend on the data inside an adapter, otherwise they won't be applied correctly after scrolling.